# Showing a root of a polynomial has minimal modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I would like to show that a certain root of the trinomial $p=x^n+x^{n-1}-1$ has the smallest modulus among all its complex roots. For the record, this polynomial is the denominator of a generating function of a combinatorial sequence that I am interested in.

I know a little bit about the polynomial. Because of a sign change ($p(0)=-1<0$ and $p(1)=1>0$), there is a root in the unit interval. If the degree $n$ is even, then $p(-1)=-1<0$ and $p(-2)=2^{n-1}-1>0$, so there is another real root in the interval $(-2,-1)$. Considering the derivative $p'=x^{n-2}(nx+n-1)$, these are the only real roots. The other $n-2$ roots (if $n$ is even) or $n-1$ roots (if $n$ is odd) are complex. I've used Maple to numerically compute the roots for many values of the degree. In each case, the roots appear on an oval centered at the origin in the complex plane. It always appears that the real root in the unit interval has the smallest modulus. Could anyone help with a proof of this?

Comment: this is immediate as if $w$ is a nonpositive root (complex or negative in the even case) and $0<a<1$ is the positive root then if $|w| < a$, we have $|w^n+w^{n-1}| \le |w|^n+|w|^{n-1}<a^n+a^{n-1}=1$ while if $|w|=a$ we still have $|w+1|<|w|+1=a+1$ since $w$ is not positive, hence again $|w^n+w^{n-1}| =a^{n-1}|w+1|<a^n+a^{n-1}=1$, so $a$ has strictly smallest modulus

Comment: @Conrad: I tried thinking along these lines, but came up short. Your reasoning is great. Case closed.